# Moving an image using Core Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

Any idea why the small image that I move across the screen gets blurry?
While being in motion, the small details in the image become unclear and I think that it is a problem.

```
        CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    anim.fromValue  = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(px2.x, px2.y)];
    anim.toValue    = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(P3x, P3y)];
    anim.duration   = 1.5f;
    anim.repeatCount =1;
    anim.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    [LA  addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually this was identified as LCD panel lag.